# Sending Messages between Services in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, interprocess

I have 2 Windows services written on .NET 4.5.1. I am looking to see if there is functionality like WinAPI's SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) call that i can use for a GUI-less process like a windows service!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send windows message to a Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233195/send-windows-message-to-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two processes need to communicate, they do so using one of any number of inter-process communication (IPC) mechanisms.  The answers to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721762/what-are-windows-ipc-methods) give you a few ideas of the possibilities.  To this I would add [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is the Microsoft-recommended way of having two .NET-based applications talk to one another.

Personally, I choose sockets for this kind of thing, but it really does come down to your particular situation and your comfort level.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use Named pipes. See here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Wow, falling back to something from Unix days, nice. Worth looking in to.