# Getting the handle of window in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do some P/Invoke stuff and need the handle of the current window.

I found [Getting the handle of window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562392/getting-the-handle-of-window-in-c-sharp)

But it appears that only works in WPF. Is there a winForms equivalent?

Comment: A link that might help with P/Invoke:
http://pinvoke.net/
Courtesy of Scott Hanselman, not me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`Control.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx)

> An `IntPtr` that contains the window handle (HWND) of the control.

Answer (score 6):

Try this in your form:

IntPtr myHandle = this.Handle;

It will return the handle of the form.