# Send key to a form even when minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, key, sendkeys

I have a very basic C# program, with a simple textbox and some other stuff.
I have a button, which triggers a timer, what I want is that with every tick of the timer I can send a key to the textbox (set so that sending a key to the form will send it to the textbox).

my code now is:

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.SendWait("ciao");
    }
```

But this works only when the form is visible and with focus

EDIT:
for some reasons I don't want to use the "textbox.text = text"

Comment: You can't use SendKeys() to target a form that is minimized.  SendKeys() only works with the application that is currently **active** and has **focus** (is open on the screen in front of the user).  For a minimized app, you'd have to get a direct **handle** to your target TextBox (possibly with FindWindow()/EnumWindows()) and then use SendMessage()/PostMessage() to send it keystrokes.

Comment: [Sending data to notepad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39706017/3110834)

Comment: You might Activate the Window and SendKeys before Deactivating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215435/event-that-triggers-before-my-form-loses-focus

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) because it sends input to the currently active window:

> Because there is no managed method to activate another application,
>   you can either use this class within the current application or use
>   native Windows methods, such as FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow, to
>   force focus on other applications.

But you can use WinAPI `SendMessage` function like it is described in greater details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3047387/3745022).

Taking into account that you know the `Form` that textbox is contained in, you can get its handle using [Control.Handle property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402848/getting-the-handle-of-window-in-c-sharp), so it will look like:

```
public static class WinApi
{
    public static class KeyBoard
    {
        public enum VirtualKey
        {
            VK_LBUTTON = 0x01,
            ...
            VK_RETURN = 0x0D
        }
    }


    public static class Message
    {
        public enum MessageType : int
        {
            WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, MessageType Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    }
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WinApi.Message.SendMessage(
        hWnd: this.textBox.Handle, // Assuming that this handler is inside the same Form.
        Msg: WinApi.Message.MessageType.WM_KEYDOWN,
        wParam: new IntPtr((Int32)WinApi.KeyBoard.VirtualKey.VK_RETURN),
        lParam: new IntPtr(1)); // Repeat once, but be careful - actual value is a more complex struct - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx
}
```

**P.S.:** You may also be interested in [`PostMessage` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376619/what-is-the-difference-between-send-message-and-post-message-and-how-these-relat).

**P.S.1:** Though this solution should work, I'd like to point that ideally you shouldn't use such mechanisms to do something inside your own application - sending keys is not always reliable and can be difficult to test. And usually there is a way to achieve the desired result without resorting to such approaches.